# jXLS to generate Excel 2007 or 2010

Tags: java, jxls

Due to the performance issue we have encountered during using jXLS 1.X, we are considering to use the jXLS 2.X library for our new project.

We want to make sure the new library can generate Excel in 2007 format, however this is not mentioned in its official [website](http://jxls.sourceforge.net).

Then I follow the "Getting Started" section in the website and succeed to generate an Excel file in 2003 format but not in 2007 format.

Does someone succeed to the use the new library to generate Excel 2007?

Answer (score 1):

jXLS 2.x supports both binary (Excel 2003) and XML based (Excel 2007 and later) formats.

The are examples in [jxls-demo repo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/overview) for both formats.

To identify the .xlsx examples look for the template file names in the [resources folder](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/32c54c41cde4a0b1666292f298c1b95e311743db/src/main/resources/org/jxls/demo/?at=master)